# Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset (Regular Exp)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am beginner with **regex**. I have the following regex :

```
/(?:"\s*or\s*"?\d)|(?:\\x(?:23|27|3d))|(?:^.?"$)|(?:(?:^["\\]*(?:[\d"]+|[^"]+"))+\s*(?:n?and|x?or|not|\|\||\&\&)\s*[\w"[+&!@(),.-])|(?:[^\w\s]\w+\s*[|-]\s*"\s*\w)|(?:@\w+\s+(and|or)\s*["\d]+)|(?:@[\w-]+\s(and|or)\s*[^\w\s])|(?:[^\w\s:]\s*\d\W+[^\w\s]\s*".)|(?:\Winformation_schema|table_name\W)\
```

When I run this regex [here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) , it works very well. But when I run it in my php script using **preg_match**, it shows

`Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 129 in...`

these are few examples of patterns which i need this regex find them :

```
"\ 26" && [
"\ 26" && +
"\ 26" && &
"\ 26" && !
"\ 26" && @
"\ 26" && (
"\ 26" && )
```

I don't want to change the structure of the regex, I need to know a PHP function to run it without error which in result can find the above example.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For starters your delimiters aren't the same. You start with `/` but end with \

Comment: @Machavity I fixed it, but still the same result!

Comment: Are you using single quotes to delimit this regex string?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos yes I am using single quotes , since if I use double quotes the regex will not work because it contais few double quotes...

Answer (score 0):

So I did some trial and error. I'm no expert on regex but I did narrow it down some. You have a lot of `OR` statements `(str1)|(str2)` so I just started cutting strings out until PHP threw one out

```
preg_match('/(?:(?:^["\\]*(?:[\d"]+|[^"]+"))+\s*(?:n?and|x?or|not|\|\||\&\&)\s*[\w"[+&!@(),.-])/', $str, $matches);
```

That produced `Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 80`. So we have our culprit. But the why is a bit more elusive. I popped it into http://regex101.com and it didn't show any problems but PHP is losing it in your character class `[\w"[+&!@(),.-]`

All I can tell you is I added another parenthesis to the start of the pattern and it works... kinda

```
$str = '"\ 26" && [';
preg_match('/((?:(?:^["\\]*(?:[\d"]+|[^"]+"))+\s*(?:n?and|x?or|not|\|\||\&\&)\s*[\w"[+&!@(),.-])/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Puts out

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(11) ""\ 26" && ["
  [1]=>
  string(11) ""\ 26" && ["
}
```

It probably needs more debugging but I can't say there's anything wrong with the regex itself. Maybe try opening a [PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

When using a parenthesis as a literal you should escape it. So instead of `[+&!@(),.-]` use `[+&!@\(\),.-]`

The behaviour when using unescaped parentheses differs from regex-enigne to regex-engine so that would explain the difference between regex101 and php.

Edit: just did some reading up and by most standards `[+&!@(),.-]` should work since the parentheses are enclosed in brackets - but escaping them would at least be worth a try.

Comment: I actually tried that but escaping the parenthesis didn't fix the problem. This is a very weird problem to be sure

Answer (score 0):

I found where is the problem.
This was my regex:

```
/(?:^["\\]*(?:[\d"]+|[^"]+")+\s*(?:n?and|x?or|not|\|\||\&\&)\s*[\w"[+&!@(),.-])/
```

now if you look at this part `["\\]` , The first \ is for escaping the second \ . however I understood when I ran my code using preg_match() , the second \ will escape the closing ] .
which results in error! 
So i fixed it by putting a space between `["\\` `]`
Now it works well:

```
/(?:^["\\ ]*(?:[\d"]+|[^"]+")+\s*(?:n?and|x?or|not|\|\||\&\&)\s*[\w"[+&!@(),.-])/
```